# Django NameError When trying Access Data

Tags: django, python-2.7

Here is the Code:

```
    from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class data_model(models.Field):
    description = "return and create data objects for visulaizations"

    def __init__(self, days, action):
        self.days = days
        self.action = action

        if(self.action == ""):
            self.action = "inspections"

        getVioPoints(self.action, self.days)
    #end init

    def getVioPoints(self):
        #get points 
        if(self.action == "violations"):
            apendQuery = "where osha_violation_indicator is true"
        elif(self.action == "inspections"):
            apendQuery = "where osha_violation_indicator is false"
        else:
            apendQuery = ""

        from django.db import connections           
        conn = connections['opengov_db'].cursor()

        conn.execute("""
            select distinct a.estab_name, b.latitude, b.longitude, a.site_address, a.site_city, a.site_state, a.site_zip
            from osha_inspection a
            join latitude_longitude_lookup b on cast(a.activity_nr as text)= b.source_data_id
            """,apendQuery,"""
            and close_case_date >= now() - interval """,self.days,""" days'
            and b.latitude is not null; """)

        row = conn.fetchone()
        print row
```

I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x9d9656c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/opengov/mapPrototypePY/opengov/map/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class data_model(models.Field):
  File "/var/www/opengov/mapPrototypePY/opengov/map/models.py", line 39, in data_model
    row = conn.fetchone()
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

And I have no idea why. I know that the query is working. But, this seems to be ignoring conn on line containing row = conn.fetchone(). I have Googled around and found nothing of note. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Also, is this the same code you are running? (what is going on with indentation?) Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe As requested.

Comment: You need to post the *full* code. Your traceback doesn't match the snippet you've posted: in particular, it seems that there is some kind of class definition (`models.Field`) that this is supposed to be part of. I suspect an indentation error, but without seeing the whole code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry about that. I have made the requested updates. As far as the indentation error, if i remove from the row = con.fetchone line down, the error goes away.

Comment: Probably some kind of indentation error. Make sure you are using 4 spaces per tab and that everything lines up.. conn is probably ending up at the class-level.

Comment: Both @DanielRoseman and Yuji were correct. It seems to have been an indentation error. Daniel since your answer was most complete, if you post an answer I will give you the credit. Thanks so much all. It is interesting that the interpreter did not give the usual indentation error. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it was an indentation error.

The reason why you didn't get an actual IndentationError on run is because the code was still syntactically valid. Probably what happened was that the code was interpreted as being at the same level as the method definitions, at class level: it's perfectly possible to have code that that level, such as setting class-level variables, and the compiler (IndentationError is a compile-time exception) doesn't know that `conn` isn't in scope at that point.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman. If you thought this question was relevant kindly give it the old thumbs up :).